# Post values with page refresh without using <form>?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

With JQuery I can easily do an AJAX post of key value pairs without a form and without a page refresh:

```
$.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: url,  data: { key: value, key: value, etc...}  });
```

But is there a way to post a set of non-form data values *with* a page refresh, or do I need to take the conventional route of setting up a set of form elements, loading their values, and then submitting the form?

thanks!

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify? I'm reading this as though you want to post the data onunload.

Comment: I have a set of serialized key/value pairs in a javascript var and I just want to post them as if they came from a conventional form submit.  Were it an ajax post I'd simply assign them to the "data" parameter of the $.ajax function.  Otherwise I need to parse through them, stick them in DOM elements under a FORM, then submit them.

Answer (score 5):

You could go the conventional route, but have jQuery *build and populate* a form dynamically if you wanted to avoid putting a `<form>` on the page.

Answer (score 2):

You can create dynamic form via jQuery, append it to body and submit it. Disadvantage: you have to generate all fields for it.

```
$('#Setting_type').change(function () {
    $('<form/>', {
        action: "/postReceiver.php",
        method: "post",
        html: "<input name='Setting[key]' value='"+$('#Setting_key').val()+"'>"
            +"<input name='Setting[type]' value='"+$('#Setting_type').val()+"'>"
            +"<input name='typeChange' value='1'>",
        class: "hidden"
    })
        .appendTo('body')
        .submit()
    ;
});
```

---

If you just want to send data via POST but still show params in query, just omit `html` attribute and put everything in `action`

```
$('#Setting_type').change(function () {
    $('<form/>', {
        action: "/postReceiver.php?type="+encodeURIComponent($('#Setting_name').val())
            +"&Setting[key]="+encodeURIComponent($('#Setting_key').val()),
        method: "post",
        class: "hidden"
    })
        .appendTo('body')
        .submit()
    ;
});
```

---

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You *could* refresh the page after the ajax post:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: {
        key1: value1,
        key2: value2,
        etc...
    },
    complete: function () {
        window.location.reload(true);
    }
});
```

But what's wrong with doing it the old-fashioned way?

<sub>[`window.location.reload` @ MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Methods)</sub>

Comment: Thanks, nothing wrong with the old fashioned way... I should have clarified that my post is to different page, which is set up to receive a conventional post.  It's kind of funny how little set up there is to do an AJAX post vs. a conventional one.

Answer (score 0):

you can always do

```
window.location = //wherever you want go
```

On ajax `success`

Comment: The page I'm posting to produces the next page upon the post.